# Dynamic Web Project Get Project Path

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a Maven Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse. I have created a webservice, the webservice calls a method from another class. Inside the class, i try to create a local folder in the folder of the project.

So far i have tried:

```
String path = new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath();

String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();

String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

String path = System.getProperty("catalina.base")
```

The first three returns the following path:

```
\eclipse\jee-mars\eclipse
```

The fourth statement returns the path:

```
\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
```

Simply, the path that i want is:

```
\workspace\MyProject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dead simple. You can't not get path:

```
\workspace\MyProject
```

because **your program/your code snippet not run at `\workspace\MyProject`**.

because after compile, build to WAR file, deploy to web application server (for exampleL Apache Tomcat), your web app run inside Tomcat, not run at `\workspace\MyProject`.